# How deep do you need to nest const constructors in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've been trying to leverage `const` constructors more in my Flutter app lately and I'm curious how deep I need to include the `const` keyword. Take the following:

```dart
const Text('foo', style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12));
```

I know I can make the `Text` widget a const because it's a static string. I can also make the `TextStyle` a const. But do I need to even include `const` on the `TextStyle` if its parent `Text` is also a `const`?

Additionally, if it is the case that I do not need to put a `const` inside a `const` and change it to the example below, will the second `TextStyle` be the same instance as the first?

```dart
const Text('foo', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12));


/// is this TextStyle the same instance as above?
Text(foo.bar, style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12));
```

I'd really appreciate any input on this. I struggle to know if I should be littering the codebase with `const` or if it's a waste of my time. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const` specifies that an object can be initialized at build time.  Therefore, `const T(x)` *requires* that `x` be known at build time, which means that it also *must* be `const`.  Therefore, for `const T(U())`, adding a `const` qualifier when constructing `U` is unnecessary; it's inferred from the context.

If `U` is not `const`-constructible, then you'll get a build-time error.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to do littering the codebase with `const`.

These are equivalent:

**BAD**

```
final b = const [const A()];
```

**GOOD**

```
final b = const [A()];
```

If you use [Lint](https://pub.dev/packages/lint) in  your project, the following rule will be useful to detect unnecessary const keywords: [unnecessary_const](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/unnecessary_const.html)

Don't struggle with these, let Lint tell you what to do.

Comment: I appreciate that! I'll definitely be adding this to my repo. Thanks!